# How to use grep and/or awk to select multiple pathnames in file and remove those files?

Tags: command-line, awk, grep, rm, xargs

I have some output that is formatted like so:

```
foo: /some/long/path_with_underscores-and-hyphens/andnumbers1.ext exists in filesystem
foo: /another/one.ext exists in filesystem
bar: /another/path/and/file.2 exists in filesystem
```

I need to remove those files. How can I extract each path and remove the file? I know that `awk` can capture the path since its always the second element in the line but I don't know where to start to grab them all and feed them into a command like `rm`.

Comment: I'm getting sent to a 404 page when I try to edit my question, but the foo:.. and bar:...'s are supposed to be on new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` and its `system()` function.

```
awk '{ system("echo rm "$2) }' list
```

Above is correct when you won't have whitespaces in your files name, if you have try below instead.

```
awk '{gsub(/^.*: | exists in filesystem$/,""); system("echo rm \"" $0"\"")}' list
```

Note that, none of the above will be able to detect newlines in files name if any.

Remove the `echo` to get ride of dry-run.

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`awk`** + **`xargs`** approach:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' file | xargs -n1 rm
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of other answers:

Does you have a file paths contain spaces? If yes then you need to handle it properly. Try to use this command to get correct file paths with GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/^.*: (.*)/\1/;s/^(.*) exists in filesystem$/\1/' file
```

Or POSIX:

```
sed -e 's/^.*: \(.*\)/\1/' -e 's/^\(.*\) exists in filesystem$/\1/' file
```

If you have file like this:

```
foo: /some/long/path_with_underscores-and-hyphens/andnumbers1.ext exists in filesystem
foo: /another/one.ext exists in filesystem
bar: /another/path/and/file.2 exists in filesystem
123 ret: /another/path/and/file 2 exists in filesystem
123 ret: /another/space path/and/file 2 exists in filesystem
```

Your output will be:

```
/some/long/path_with_underscores-and-hyphens/andnumbers1.ext
/another/one.ext
/another/path/and/file.2
/another/path/and/file 2
/another/space path/and/file 2
```

To delete file use `xargs` as mentioned above but with `-d` option:

```
sed pattern | xargs -n1 -d '\n' rm
```